# Feasibility of an uninterruptible power supply based on over-the-counter domestic batteries

Tags: power-supply, battery-operated

Is it possible to buy or easily manufacture a UPS which runs on AA/AAA batteries? Specifically, I operate a Linux system which regularly experiences hard shutdowns (plug pulled from wall etc.) This is damaging the file system and possibly the hardware. I'm wondering if I could add a UPS which the system runs on while it shuts down gracefully.

I'm keen to use common batteries which can be added optionally if an operator wishes to protect their system.

Comment: Why use one time disposable batteries for a recurring problem?  There's a very good reason that a UPS has  a rechargeable battery.

Comment: Any reasonable filesystem designed in the last two decades should have journalling and should thus be immune to damage by power cuts. Are you using something exotic?

Answer (score 8):

Completely impractical.

Take a [typical AA cell.](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/e91.pdf)  It has a usable capacity under heavy load (500mA) of maybe 2 watt hours of energy.

Compare that with a [not especially high power UPS model from Amazon.](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Uninterruptible-sockets-shut-off-software-protection-black/dp/B07P7LF5MR/ref=mp_s_a_1_7?brr=1&qid=1666347341&rd=1&s=computers&sr=1-7)  It can deliver up to 900 watts.  It has two large batteries in it with a combined capacity of over 200 watt hours.

To replace the sealed lead acid batteries in that UPS, you'd need something like 100 AA cells - and you'd have to replace them every time you had a power failure.  That's two of [these huge packages of AA cells](https://www.amazon.de/Amazon-Basics-Alkaline-Batteries-Appearance-gray/dp/B00MNV8E0C/ref=mp_s_a_1_4?keywords=aa+battery&qid=1666347828&qu=eyJxc2MiOiI1LjM2IiwicXNhIjoiNS4xMCIsInFzcCI6IjQuOTkifQ%3D%3D&sr=8-4) at twenty US dollars a pack - forty bucks everytime you have a power failure (or one pack of one hundred for 36 bucks - big savings, woot!)  On top of that, of course, is the problems you will have with poor contacts in the battery holders (massive reliability problems.)

A standard UPS is what you want.  It'll recharge and maintain its batteries for several years.  Install [NUT](https://networkupstools.org/) on your Linux system (or the manufacturer supplied software if you use Windows) and set it up to shutdown the computer when the power fails.

It'll be cheaper, and the environment will thank you for not using throw away (polluting) one-way cells.

Comment: Not *completely* impractical -- if the Linux system is running on a Raspberry Pi, a UPS using four AA NiMH batteries can run it for an hour or so.

Comment: @Mark:  The question doesn't mention the specific case of a low power single board computer.  It was a general question about UPS.  I considered the case of a Raspberry Pi, and decided not to go into it so as not to clutter up a general answer with special cases.

Comment: In any case, disposable primary cells rather than rechargeable is a bad idea.